# What is the difference between Protestantism and Evangelicalism?

Tags: protestantism, evangelicalism

What is the difference between Protestantism and Evangelicalism? Are all Protestants also Evangelicals? Are all Evangelicals also Protestants?

Comment: Good question but if I were to answer I would start by laying out about 15 different definitions for each term and showing how you could argue this either way. Whose definitions of these very general terms are you interested in?

Comment: @Caleb Are there any definitions that are remotely considered the most common?

Comment: For Protestantism, there are a couple common ones. For Evangelicalism, I don't know of any that I would consider binding or useful -- although from context one can often surmise what people mean by it, since there is so much diversity of intended meaning I don't actually consider it a meaningful moniker.

Comment: "Evangelical" is almost an adjective that inherits its meaning from the noun it purports to describe. Definitively not the usual role for that part of speech.

Comment: I agree with Caleb.  "Evangelical" is an somewhat generic adjective that can even apply to [Evangelical Catholicism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Catholic).  Compare "Evangelical" to "Evangelicalism" (which is a [Protestant Movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelicalism)).  Big, broad terms here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evangelicalism is a kind of Protestantism.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelicalism):

> Evangelicalism is a Protestant Christian movement which began in Great
> Britain in the 1730s and gained popularity in the United States
> during the series of Great Awakenings of the 18th and 19th century.
> Its key commitments are:
>
> 1. The need for personal conversion (or being "born again")
> 2. A high regard for biblical authority
> 3. An emphasis on teachings that proclaim the saving death and resurrection of the Son
>    of God, Jesus Christ
> 4. Actively expressing and sharing the gospel.

Contrast this with the traditional lutheran church that does not have the concept of being "born again" (1), also believes in the Tradition (2), don't know about (3) and traditionally being a part of the power mechanisms of its countries (4).

Comment: Don't forget about [Evangelical Catholics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Catholic)...

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! Glad to have you around ... when you get a chance you might check out our [FAQ](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq) and the [featured tag on meta](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) to get an idea of what we're working on around here, just know that we're still a work in progress...

Comment: @Richard, I'm pretty sure 'Evangelical Catholic' is sort of just a renewal movement like the 'Charismatic Catholic' etc.  Except their goal is directed more at the mission of the Church than nurturing spiritual gifts.  Only mentioning this because I don't think that wikipedia article is very illuminating.  There was an Evangelical Catholic club or something at the Parish on the UW-Madison Campus where I went to school, I never got involved, but they seemed like they were doing normal Catholic stuff, just a little louder.

Comment: In Continental Europe, Evangelical is actually a synonym for Lutheran. And it begun much earlier than 1730.